# Neo4j 2.2.0 show/delete node with no properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've got a node with no properties in it and want to show/find it then delete it.
It shows up as blank and has a [:KNOWS] relationship to 2 other nodes.

(null node)-[:KNOWS]->(Ian),(Johan)

I can't just Match nodes with no name property because I have other nodes with no name property.

Is it possible to show this node then delete it? Also, is this possible to do in the webadmin > Data browser?

Thanks,
M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you match against a node with no properties and that relationship? Or are there others that would be matched that you want avoid deleting?

I mean:

```
MATCH (n)-[r:KNOWS]->(p:Person)
WHERE p.name IN ["Ian","Johan"]
DELETE r,n;
```

If you have other nodes which might be matched by this query, you can try excluding those by implying that n should not have a specific property:

```
MATCH (n)-[r:KNOWS]->(p:Person)
WHERE p.name IN ["Ian","Johan"]
AND NOT has(n.name)
DELETE r,n;
```

You might want to test the results first before actually deleting:

```
MATCH (n)-[:KNOWS]->(p:Person)
WHERE p.name IN ["Ian","Johan"]
AND NOT has(n.name)
RETURN n;
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks so much albertoperdomo!

Do I need to also delete the relationships for the null node? If so, how to do this?

Comment: Glad it helped! Sorry I forgot about the relationships. Yes, Neo4j won't let you delete a node if it has any relationships. I've just updated the code snippets to delete also the relationships. Note you assign a name to the rels (r) and then include that in the DELETE clause.